# android- Converting pdf into images

Tags: android, pdf, converters

I'm developing an Android application which involves reading pdf files.

Initially on syncing with the server a set of pdf files will be saved into the device's SD card.

Now, I have a requirement to convert this pdf file into images. Because on doing that the speed of loading the pages are faster..

can anyone help me with this and if possible give me links to some sample code..

I got this idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779852/1105585 ....
but i don't know how this works... help plz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On desktop I've used [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) java library for that kind of task. Not sure if its Android compatible but worth of giving a shot as its easy to implement.

Comment: Its open source so with slight changes I am sure it will work

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on an app that loads files and adds effects to the images. One of the formats suppose to support is PDF. I used leadtools libs for the rasterrizing pdfs (converting pdf into raster images) and some image effects.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

PDF isn't made up of images, they're vectors,.

couple open-source java PDF to Image converters 
http://www.jpedal.org/

http://code.google.com/p/pdfonejava/